# How to set new port while serving application through static-server in React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have two applications which I want to run on two different ports. I am using webpack to bundle all my static contents in a dist folder and running the static-server. static-server default runs on 9080 and the first application runs perfectly fine. However, when I try to run the second application, I get an error that port is already in use. So I am setting a new PORT for another application so that it serves on that port. To do so, I am doing something like below.
In my package.json-

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot  --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start:prod": "set PORT=3006 && cd dist && static-server"
  }
```

I am not able to set the port to 3006 and instead when I try to run status-server inside list folder, I get an error-

```
* Shutting down server

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::9080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
    at StaticServer.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/static-server/server.js:114:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/static-server/bin/static-server.js:48:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
```

I also tried to set port in my webpack.config.js inside deserver but still getting the same issue. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If your in a unix-based environment (mac or linux), you need to set the port like this: `PORT=3006 static-server ./dist`

Comment: I do cd dist and then run static-server. yes, I am trying in Mac, but its not running in my localhost.

Comment: It still gives me the same port error.

Comment: try this one: `static-server -p 3306`

Comment: if I give this on cli, it works but I want this to be in my package.json. when I am adding this in my package.json, it gives the same previous error.

Comment: This works!! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the port to your process, as an argument, not as an environment variable, like:

```
static-server -p 8080
```

**Some notes on setting environment variables**

If you're in a UNIX-based Operating system link macOS or Linux, there are multiple ways to set environment variables:

1. If you want the variable to be only set for the latter command, you
   should use it this way

   `PORT=8080 npm run dev.`
2. If you want to set the variable for the entire terminal session, you should set it this way

   `$ set -a
   $ PORT=8080
   & yarn run dev`
3. You can add it to your `~/.zshrc` / `~/.bashrc` `~/.profile` to have it always in your terminal:

   `export PORT=8080`